# NuxtJS change query params and reload page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

I have a route in my NuxtJS application that accept query parameters. I'm trying to implement a logic that allow the user to change the query parameters and reload the page.

I tried:

```js
// this does not work because I'm already in "mypage" and "push" does not reload the same page
this.$router.push(`/mypage?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}`)

// same result as above
this.$router.push({ path: '/mypage', query: {param1: value1, param2: value2}})

// this is able to change the query parameters but on reload they are reverted to the originals
this.$router.replace({ query: {param1: value1, param2: value2} })
window.location.reload()

// This reload the page but the query parameters are reverted as well
this.$router.go(`/mypage?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}`)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the purpose of using `reload`?

Comment: to refresh the page after having changed the query parameters but it doesn't work

Comment: But Vue is reactive, the changes should be expected to happen without a refresh.  It's not a good practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the 2nd method to update query params.

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/mypage', query: {param1: value1, param2: value2}})
```

It's really a bad practice to force reload a page, instead, you should set up a watcher or a computed for your query.

E.g.

```
  watch: {
    '$route.query'() {
      // do something
    }
  },
```

If this doesn't work for your please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what would I put in the watcher if I want to reload the page with the new parameters?

Comment: You can always reload the page with this.$router.go(0), but as I said in the answer, you really shouldn't do this because NuxtJs is reactive. In 99% of cases, you can solve the problem in some other way (methods, vuex, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

### This is only a workaround:

thanks to this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1182#issuecomment-405326772

I was able to work around the issue by using javascript:

```js
window.history.pushState({},'',`/mypage?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}`)
window.location.reload()
```

of course this is not an optimal solution but it gets the work done until someone come out with a more proper solution here. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it use promise.then() and $nuxt.refresh()

```
// before

this.$router.replace({ query: {param1: value1, param2: value2} })
window.location.reload()

// after

this.$router.replace({ query: {param1: value1, param2: value2} }).then(() => {
  this.$nuxt.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use watchQuery

```
export default {
  watchQuery: ['page']
}
```

Doc: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/watchquery/#the-watchquery-property

Answer (score 0):

if u want only to change query param without reloading the page, use [Fabio Magarelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318359/3166417) solution:

```
window.history.pushState({},'',`/mypage?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}`)
```

for change with reload - use this:

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$route.path, query: { param1: 'param1', param2: 'param2' }})
```